# Creating XML file from PowerShell command output

Tags: xml, powershell

I have not worked with XML much so this may be a basic question to most...

I want to collect information from Get-ChildItem, combined with Get-Acl, and store it in an XML file so I can use it later within PowerShell.

The issue: in order for me to use the Get-Acl I have to use a foreach loop within the pipeline, which is in turn changing the object type to system.string. So when I export that to XML it is pretty much just a flat file, not table structure.

How can I get the table structure back?

If I just do this command I can get the table structure:

```
Get-ChildItem . -Recurse | 
Select FullName, PSIsContainer, CreationTimeUTC, LastAccessTimeUtc, Length | 
Export-Clixml .\STIGTest\Baseline_1.xml
```

When I do this command, which is what I need, I get the flat file:

```
Get-ChildItem . -Recurse | 
foreach-object {$AclOwner = (get-acl $_.pspath).owner; $_.Fullname, $_.PSIsContainer, $_.CreationTimeUtc, $_.LastAccessUtc, $_.Length, $AclOwner} | 
Export-Clixml .\STIGTest\Baseline_2.xml
```

I have seen where you can convert a system object to a string but can't seem to find where I can do the reverse. I am guessing if they stay as a system object the XML file will keep the table structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this one a try. It takes advantage of the fact that `Select-Object` can create "calculated" properties specified by an expression.

```
Get-ChildItem . -Recurse | 
Select FullName,
       PSIsContainer,
       CreationTimeUTC,
       LastAccessTimeUtc,
       Length,
       @{Name='Owner';Expression={ (Get-Acl $_.PSPath).Owner }} | 
Export-Clixml .\STIGTest\Baseline_1.xml
```

I wrote `@{Name=...; Expression=...}` for clarity but they can be shortened to `@{N=...,E=...}`.

Comment: AH, I've seen that used in PS script I was given for SQL Server. That was the magic. So for my understanding the @{} is a hashtable? What term would I use to look up information on use of that, maybe under Select-object?

Comment: Awesome! That also fixes my next task of collecting the ACL info for each file. Love this stuff!!!

Answer (score 0):

@Josh Einstein's answer and from the link I had given in the comment, the other answer is the way to go. But there is another way by which you can add the acl information to the object itself, and the below adds up on what you were trying as mentioned in the question:

```
Get-ChildItem . -recurse | 
foreach-object {$AclOwner = (get-acl $_.pspath).owner; Add-Member -input $_ -MemberType noteproperty -Name AclOwner -Value $AclOwner; $_ } | 
Select FullName, PSIsContainer, CreationTimeUTC, LastAccessTimeUtc, Length, AclOwner |
Export-Clixml .\STIGTest\Baseline_1.xml
```

Comment: So you added pulling the full user account, with domain/hostname?

Would this make a difference if I'm using the XML file as a baseline to compare snapshots of the directory to pick up changes made?

Comment: @MeltonDBA - I am not understanding exactly what you are asking, but the xml generated from above should be the same as the one generated in the other way.